# Как убрать число из дублирующего заголовка записи в вордпрессе

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть CPT (has archive: true). С помощью плагина ACF в каждую запись данной CPT добавляется дата. Через плагин Permalink Manager Pro в слаг записи добавляется указанная дата `%__event-date%-%post%`.

Если в другой записи ее название дублируется, то в конце слага добавляется "-2". Дата, указанная в начале слага, никак не влияет.

Я в курсе что это защита от дублей, но в таком случае пропадает смысл автоматического добавления в слаг записи даты.

Можно ли каким-то образом убрать добавления числа (-2)?

Если добавятся две записи с одинаковым именем в один день, то тогда уже и можно добавлять двойку `%__event-date%-%post%-2`

Answer (score 0):

Генерацией таких URL занимается функция из ядра WordPress [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_unique_post_slug), которая имеет ряд хуков:

- `pre_wp_unique_post_slug`
- `wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_attachment_slug`
- `wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug`
- `wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug`
- `wp_unique_post_slug`